# how to redirect to new page by selecting an option in datalist

Tags: php, html

I have created a datalist here how can I add a link to option so that whenever i select a option and click on submit i should redirect to another page based on selected option.I have googled  a lot but I couldn't any information about this.Thanks in advance

```
 <input list="category" name="category">
   <datalist id="category">
      <option value="fruits">
      <option value="animals">
      <option value="vechiles">
      <option value="ornaments">
  </datalist>
<input type="submit">
```

Comment: Can you please post your detail list here?

Comment: `<?if(isset($_POST)) header('Location: /path/to/location')?>`

Comment: Try onchange() function, get the value from option, set the condition and on submit redirect it.

Comment: about which list i need to give details

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code :

```
     <input list="category" name="category" id="textcat">
   <datalist id="category">
      <option id="www.google.com" value="fruits">
      <option id="www.fb.com" value="animals">
      <option id="www.ymail.com" value="vechiles">
      <option id="www.msn.com" value="ornaments">
  </datalist>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="submit">

    <script>

    $('#btn').click(function(){
    var textval = $('#textcat').val();
    $('#category option').each(function(){
        if($(this).val() == textval){
            alert($(this).attr('id'));
            window.location = $(this).attr('id');
        }
    });
});

    </script>
```

Comment: If i use this,I need to use a lot of if statements which will be complex if i add 100 options

Comment: The you can set directly URL into option value..then it will be very simple for thousands of options.. you can then use directly **window.location = $(this).val()**

Comment: Thats what i am asking how can i add that url into option tag

Answer (score 0):

Make some formHandler.php in which you will some routing, and point your form (action="formHandler.php") that includes this select

```
$redirectLink=$_REQUEST['category'];
header('Location:'.$yourmainSitePath.'/'.$redirectLink)
```

Are you satisfied ? :D